# How to make eclipse display proposals on "style" attribute in JSF tags?

Tags: eclipse, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am currently developing a dynamic web application using eclipse.
If I create a JSF (XHTML) file and place any JSF/Primefaces tag, and create a style to this tag, when I hit CTRL+SPACE it shows me no proposals. On the other hand, if I place default HTML components like DIV, SPAN, etc, It works fine.

This is what is happening:

```
<h:outputText style="CTRL+SPACE-SHOWS NO PROPOSAL" value="some value" />
```

Comment: Are you expecting css-proposals inside the style tag or proposals for attributes regarding JSF tags? The last one might be available activating the Facet for JavaServer Faces (<yourProject>->Properties->Project Facets).

Comment: It is already configured!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a project facet.

Right click on the Project --> Preferences --> Project Facets --> Finally, click on JavaServer Faces and add the library if it's not yet installed, otherwise click on disable.

Comment: It was already configured like you said. Even with Java Server Faces checked, it don't work.